# Help wanted to identify this food item (oriental)

Tags: food-identification

I found this item at a Chinese supermarket.

[image]

Hints:

1. It was in a fridge
2. It was humid (almost wet) and fresh
3. The "slices" were 2-3 mmm thick

I googled for "Chopin", "Chopin food", "Chopin Chinese", etc. to no avail. Too many music related hits returned!

Comment: Is it a dough? I can imagine it being used as the outer shell for dumplings. But it is hard to tell just from a picture, it could be saitan in sheets too, or something completely different.

Comment: @rumtscho No, it wasn't a dough. But I can't say if it was an animal or vegetal byproduct

Comment: I asked an Asian colleague at work and he said that the Chinese label on the box says dried cabbage but he hasn't seen anything like this before

Comment: @rumtscho do you mean __seitan__ as in wheat protein?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those appear to be bean curd sheets (ie. tofu sheets).
They're a common find in Asian shops.

Here's what they look like when nice and fresh
 [image: Here's what they look like when nice and fresh]

But they can also be dried.
[image: But they can also be dried.]

The OP picture looks like it's somewhere in between; maybe hasn't been cared for too well. It looks like it should look like the first photo but has been left uncovered and has dried around the edges.

I think the cabbage label is just a simple mistake/misplacement. Dried or cured cabbage would still have a visible cellulose structure while the OP picture has a consistent look (if not tofu, then it's certainly something reformed from something like flour or meal - seitan as mentioned in a comment is a likely runner-up).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Do you have any clue about the "chopin" label?

Comment: "I think the cabbage label is just a simple mistake/misplacement." Make sense. The item itself could really be tofu sheets!

Comment: @belisarius Mybe a close photo showing the texture detail would be enough :)

Comment: @Silvia I doubt I can do better than this http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEJa6.png

Comment: @belisarius Have you tasted it? Tofu sheets are usually not salty while dried cabbages are very salty. Does it touch like leather?

Comment: @Silvia I haven't tasted it but yes, it felt like (wet) leather or skin

Comment: @belisarius Then it might be tofu sheet. Other than tasting it, you might try take a small sample and burn it. If it's tofu, there should be significant smell like burning any protein (like hair). If it's cabbage then not.

Comment: @Silvia OK. You'll have an answer during next week, when I stop by for my dose of 麻辣臭豆腐

Comment: @belisarius Looking forward to that:D 麻辣臭豆腐 sounds yummy! ¡Buen provecho!

Answer (score 11):

"高麗" is the [ancient name of Korea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goryeo). However, "高麗菜" (where "菜" means *vegetable*) has nothing to do with Korea, but just how people call [*cabbage*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabbage) in Taiwan and Fujian. (It's unclear why people use this phrase.) The making process involve drying the cabbage leaves in the sun, so it's called "乾" (in simplified Chinese "干"), which is the name of *the Sky* in the [*Bagua*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagua), so the category name of any dried things.

According to [this blog from Taiwan](http://blog.xuite.net/ma522/blog/30437466-%E6%9B%AC%E9%AB%98%E9%BA%97%E8%8F%9C%E4%B9%BE%E8%B6%A3) (it was written in traditional Chinese, but you can see the photos to have some rough impression about how the blogger made the 高麗菜乾 for her/his own family using:), people hang up the cabbages on shelves and dry them in the sun untill the cabbages become dry and soft, then salt it and rub it gently, then wait until it become soft (I guess also more pliable), then put a heavy stone on them to push the remaining moisture out of the leaves, then again hang them and dry in the sun, this time, untill completely dried. Now you can seal them in containers and keep them in fridges.

So for conclusion, I believe it's a kind of [cured cabbage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curing_%28food_preservation%29) maybe produced in Taiwan, and if you like cured food it should be delicious! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Silvia! Very informative answer. I'll buy a few the next time I go there!

Comment: @belisarius Always my pleasure :)

Comment: @belisarius buy, don't loot. So nice to see this helpful extraMMA interaction between you two :)

Comment: @Rojo Best Chinese (price/performance) in BA https://www.facebook.com/pages/Restaurant-Palitos/284659821556010

Comment: @belisarius Thanks :). Hopefully I'll check it out soon

Comment: @Rojo @ belisarius If you come to China, I will be very glad to show you some authentic local food :)